# How to make the path in Kubernetes Ingress case-insensitive?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to configure a Kubernetes Ingress resource to make the path case-insensitive. Here is my current Ingress configuration:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: APP
  namespace: NAMESPACE
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /Foo
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: APP
                port:
                  number: 80
```

the above ingress should work for foo,Foo and FOO

Is there a way to make the path in Kubernetes Ingress case-insensitive? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What ingress controller are you using? The nginx controller supports case-insensitive paths if you configure a setting. See the docs at https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/.

Comment: I am using traefik ingress controller, There is some restrictions to use nginx controller

Comment: I do not think Traefix supports a regex path. You have the option to provide a path list though so perhaps something like `"/foo , /Foo, /FOo, /FOO"` could work but that would be painful for all combinations of a non-trivial name. Alternatively, do you have the ability to 'fix' the URI at a prior point/edge/gateway in the flow so that only lower/upper case paths make it to the ingress?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a comment from [pleshakov](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/issues/964#issuecomment-632951653) that may help with to make the kubernetes ingress case sensitive. According to pleshakov, this is not a built-in feature and need to modify the template.

You can add a [custom annotation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/custom-annotations/) by modifying the Ingress template:

You need to replace this line:

```
 location {{$location.Path}} {
```

with this line:

```
location {{if index $.Ingress.Annotations "custom.nginx.org/regex-insensitive-prefix"}}~* ^{{end}}{{$location.Path}} {
```

Then you will be able to turn on case insensitive matching in the Ingress resource:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: cafe-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    custom.nginx.org/regex-insensitive-prefix: "true"
spec:
. . .
```

Comment: I am not using nginx ingress controller, I am using Traefik